# priorityQueue java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

I am following a a guide and trying to learn Java. I am running Java version 10.0.1. All my other codes compile just fine. but I keep getting the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class priorityQueuePractice.PriorityQueue
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: priorityQueuePractice.PriorityQueue

This seems like I am missing something. The tutorial I am following has the same exact code, so I am not sure what is different about mine.

```
package pQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public class PQueue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Integer> Heaps = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

        Heaps.add(4);
        Heaps.add(34);
        Heaps.add(62);
        Heaps.add(72);

        for(Integer x: Heaps)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }

        System.out.println(Heaps.element() + " " + Heaps.peek() );

        while (!Heaps.isEmpty() )
        {
            System.out.println(Heaps.poll() );
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched for a few days now and I cannot find a solution to this. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated!

Comment: How do you run your code? At first glance you may need to change `priorityQueuePractice.PriorityQueue` to `pQueue.PQueue` and may need to read about packages and classpath in Java

Comment: just being thorough incase someone is as new ans needs assistance. Manually you can go to -Run/Debug settings and edit launch configuration inside of eclipse. in a command line environment I dont think this would have been an issue